# Check Eval() with function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a function that checks if the price has a discount, and if it does it should output a calculated value, but i can't seem to get it working. Anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

ASP.NET: (Extraction from DB is working as intended)

```
<%# DiscountFunction(Eval("status"), Eval("price"), Eval("procent"))%>
```

Code behind:

```
public string DiscountFunction(string status, string price, string discount)
    {
        if(status == "True") {
            int price2 = Convert.ToInt32(price);
            int discount2 = Convert.ToInt32(discount);
            int calc = (price2 / 100) * discount2;
            int final_calc = pris2-calc;
            return price + " " + final_calc;
        } else {
            return price.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error that my function contains invalid arguments.

Comment: Is your data type pass correctly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

```
<%# DiscountFunction(Eval("status").ToString(), Eval("price").ToString(), Eval("procent").ToString())%>
```

you have to convert to string because `Eval` function have return object type  not string so you have to implicitly convert it to string before passing to your function because it require string type arguments not object type.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked..
I'm encountering another problem now though. That the function fails if my Eval strings is empty. What can i do about that?

Comment: instead of tostring() do like  this{ Eval("status") as string, Eval("price") as string, Eval("procent") as string}....because  tostrng() return's exception when its is null.....

Comment: Even better, change the parameters' type of the method to int, to avoid converting int to string to int.